# Linux curl : no url found (or) curl: malformed url

Tags: linux, docker, curl, docker-compose

So I am downloading docker setup on my linux vm, and have to run this command as part of the steps, but even though it mentions url, and I changed once `-o` to `-O` but still getting those errors, what to do for this?
this is the command im running

```
sudo curl -L $(curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | grep "browser_download_url" |  grep "$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)\"" | sed -nr 's/\s+"browser_download_url":\s+"(https.*)"/\1/p') -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` that is filtering what system you are running is outputting an upper case L in Linux, this may be the cause of your errors. Try this:

```
sudo curl -L $(curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | grep "browser_download_url" |  grep -i "$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)\"" | sed -nr 's/\s+"browser_download_url":\s+"(https.*)"/\1/p') -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Hope this helps!